# What material is Batman's suit made of in Dawn of Justice?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Does anybody know what is his suit made out of? I saw the tech guide and I didn't get anything.

Comment: You mean the one he fought Superman in or the normal one?

Comment: The armoured power-suit / exoskeleton in BvS is heavily based on the one Bats uses in _The Dark Knight Returns_, but there's no mention of the materials that one is made of either. If I had to guess though, I'd say it was probably some kind of Titanium-Steel alloy. It has to withstand punches from Superman, after all.

Comment: Yes the normal suit. Not the armored one.

Comment: I think they said in the movie that it is a kevlar nomex tri-weave, but I'm not certain. That's been a thing for a long time now though. It's not a quite real material, but very close to being real.

Comment: @Durakken You should make that an answer, it's better than the two answers as of the time of writing this comment.

Comment: Just to clarify are you talking about the material used to make the costume or the in-universe material used to make the suit?

Answer (score -1):

The metal suit is called the meck suit. Not sure what it stands for, but I have the movie and in the extras it tells you it's made from a lead alloy, and when Ben Affleck was wearing it he couldn't see.